# Tools to combine a video with an animated logo

Tags: video-editor, software-recommendation

I'm wondering, what tools would you suggest that I use to create an animated logo like the following.

Say I have a logo that represents a roaring tiger head. I would like to have an intro video that would show the tiger walking and suddenly open his mouth to roar.

It is at this precise moment that I would like to paste the logo on top of the tiger head with a fading effect. So in the end only the logo is displayed with its slogan. The point is to show where this logo design came from.

It would be a nice effect and I can only imagine it's a very simple task for experienced video editors, but for me I have no clue where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, here is my solution. I separate your video with animated with 3 parts: intro video with walking and roaring tiger, fading logo and logo with slogan. As per your mentioned that you may be a green hand for video editing software, therefore Premiere or After Effects may be too complicate for you. You can try some simple video editing software like I answered [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4233/simple-video-editing-tool/9384#9384).

1. Step one, find a walking and roaring tiger YouTube video like this
   One:

   , then download it
   via YouTube downloader, Google it, you will find some free
   Downloader (because it's not friendly to YouTube, you may need to
   take caution)
2. Step two,  cut/edit this video with the simple video editing tools
   You picked above, only keep the useful scene, i.e. walking and
   Roaring part, save it to your pc first.
3. Step three, Google tiger head cartoon, you will find multiple
   suitable tiger head logo, but you may need to touch up before use it
   as your logo. If you already have one, perfect, you can just import
   to that video editor, drag and drop to the timeline, applying fading
   transaction, save it to your pc again.
4. Step four, at this point you need PIP function (make sure the
   software you picked up has this function). Import the two video clip
   and drag and drop the first one(made on step two) to video track and
   drop the second one to PIP track, adjust the size and position of
   your second video, which can be positioned above the tiger head,
   fading at the same time, that's the PIP value.
5. Step five, import logo to that video editor and them drag to
   image/media track (this logo should be put at the end of the
   previous video), add text with the slogan you need.
6. Last step, export and save them to your pc, your video with animated
   logo completed. All those steps can be achieved by my software (you
   can check my profile), which is very simple to use and will be
   suitable for green hands like you. Good luck for you!

Comment: Thank you so much for this very detailed answer that will not only help me but others as well. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

The big trick is just finding the right source clip that will fit with the logo, though it also depends on how closely you want it to match up.  Simply layering the logo over top of a video clip and fading it in is trivial with any editing or compositing software package (such as Premiere or After Effects).

To get a little more advanced you can actually build the logo off the video clip so that it is an exact match (if you don't already have a finalized logo that you have to use).  If you do, you can try making an animated logo using either vector graphics or 3d graphics that will start at the way the video looks and transition to the way the logo looks, but that is far more complicated.  You could also try to use morphing software which might be able to do it for you, though I don't know of any good, current morphing software as I haven't done any morphing in a while.

Finally, the most complex would be to do the entire thing in 3d animation software, but that would require a lot of time and resources to do.  Really, any of the things involving 3d animation are going to require an experienced professional to do, so your best bet is probably going to be either the basic position and fade or trying to find a video morphing program that can handle the transition.

Comment: Hi AJ Henderson and thanks for your advice. I googled morphing soft and found morpheus photo animation suite which seems to provide the possibility to save as .avi format. To make my transition, I will make a print screen of the tiger in the video and use it for the morphing. But then how do you suggest me to combine the tiger video with morphed .avi video so that everything is smooth? Thanks

Comment: @JulianLivin'inChina - that is just basic editing.  Play the video up until the frame that you start the morphing, then play the morphing clip, then put a still image of the logo positioned and sized to the same place as the end of the morph video.  It should be a trivial thing to do in whatever editing software you choose, but the exact details depend on the software you use.